# Returning objects in php

Tags: php, object

I see similar questions asked but I seem to have problem with more basic stuff than were asked. How to declare a variable in php? My specific problem is I have a function that reads a DB table and returns the record (only one) as an object.

```
class User{
   public $uid;
   public $name;
   public $status;
}

function GetUserInfo($uid)
{
   // Query DB

   $userObj = new User();

   // convert the result into the User object.

   var_dump($userObj);   
   return $userObj;
}

// In another file I call the above function.

....

$newuser = GetUserInfo($uid);

var_dump($newuser);
```

What is the problem here, I cannot understand. Essentially the `var_dump()` in the function `GetUserInfo()` works fine. The `var_dump()` outside after the call to `GetUserInfo()` does not work.

Comment: It should be okay. Are you 1000% sure you are comparing the right `var_dump()` s, i.e. the one inside the function really happens immediately before `var_dump($newuser)`? There is no other place where your function gets called?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Sounds like you are on PHP4. Please upgrade to 5.3, because anything less is complete garbage. I seriously hope you don't have any clients because if you are writing PHP4 code for them... they need to fire you.

Comment: What do you mean with "var_dump() does not work"?

Comment: No. I am not using php4.

Comment: Sorry guys turns out there is a typo in my code and it was not showing up in my IDE. I had to go through the apache logs to see that. 

I am using the eclipse IDE for php. It is total BS. Does not show a thing except for blatant language specific errors.

Comment: So, funny story. I was having the same problem you were went through everything and I had the same issue in my code. 1 letter was off in the variable name. So if anyone else is having this issue LOOK FOR TYPOS!

haha

Answer (score 13):

Using PHP5 it works:

```
<pre>
<?php

class User{
   public $uid;
   public $name;
   public $status;
}

function GetUserInfo($uid)
{

   $userObj = new User();
   $userObj->uid=$uid;
   $userObj->name='zaf';
   $userObj->status='guru';
   return $userObj;
}

$newuser = GetUserInfo(1);
var_dump($newuser);

?>
</pre>

object(User)#1 (3) {
  ["uid"]=>
  int(1)
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "zaf"
  ["status"]=>
  string(4) "guru"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a new instance of your `User` class. Then use that instance to call your function and provide the $uid parameter so your query gets executed like it shoudl. If there is a match in your datatable your Userobject will get filled with the DB-results.

Personally I prefer using the static calls, it makes your code much more readable and compact.

Difference:

```
$userObj = new User();
$user = $userObj->GetUserInfo('your uid');
```

Or

```
$user = User::GetUserInfo('your uid');
```

And I see a strange `}` at line 4. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it should be after the `}` from the function `GetUserInfo($uid)`.

Comment: From the code sample above, the GetUserInfo() function isn't a method on the class, it's a separate function.

Comment: I've noticed that too, after i posted my first answer. But then it's a wacky implementation of an OOP solution to get a UserObject, at least, in my opinion.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that if he just moves the accolade to the line after the GetUserInfo function (which then becomes a method) it should work fine. P.s. don't forget to add the prefix `public` in front of `function`.

Comment: Ben, I was simplifying the code for the sake of posting. I do understand its not a good OOP implementation. 


I did find the problem though, its a lot sillier than I thought like I mentioned above. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome ;) I was not implifieng that you don't know OOP ;)

Comment: implifieng? he he.. I like the spelling even better.

Comment: @User220201: Yeah I'm sorry for the typo!, @Unknown: It's a real treat getting downvoted without any comment, even though I gave a working solution!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue. However I'm using 5.6.1. Here's what I was doing wrong:

```
class component
{
    public function myFunc() 
    {
        $obj = new SomeComp();
        try {
            do some work 
            return $obj;
        } finally {
            $obj = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything in the class method worked fine, $obj had information when returning. However the results of the following provided a null value:

```
$myClass = new component();
$myObj = $myClass->myFunc();
var_dump($myObj);  // returns NULL
```

Setting $obj = null; in the class method try...finally destroyed $obj making $myObj NULL. Removed the $obj = null; and the method return the proper information.

Answer (score 0):

new stdClass(); should fix the problem.